# SetText in TextWatcher

Tags: android, settext, textwatcher

I have problem a problem with `setText()` method. When I type numbers in numeric keyboard after `setText` numeric keyboard changes automaticaly to characters keyboard. How can I dissmis this action?

```
textWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                editText.removeTextChangedListener(textWatcher);

                String group = s.toString().toUpperCase();

                editText.setText(group);    
                editText.setSelection(editText.getText().length());
                editText.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
            }
        };
```

Comment: Just to add this in afterTextChanged function. editText.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same problem. U deen to use `RelativeLayout` and `TextView` with your `EditText`

And in `afterTextChanged` use `setText` to a `textView`.
[Here is more detail.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11429077/android-settext-changes-keyboard-type/11444544#11444544)

Answer (score 1):

Write this

```
editText.setRawInputType(TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | TYPE_NUMBER_VARIATION_NORMAL);
```

after

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
```

Comment: after first symbol input it switch to number keyboard and dont let to switch back to symbols

Comment: Yes. It changes TYPE_CLASS_TEXT to TYPE_CLASS_NUMBERS and I cant switch back. I just need to use default keyboard but when I am inputing some symbol from "?123" keyboard `setText()` method switch back to the 'ABC' and I'm trying to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

In your xml file in EditText tag add

```
android:inputType="number"
```

mark as answered if this solution helped you

Comment: I need to type characters and numbers. But when I try to type number it changes automaticaly to characters keyboard from numeric.